# How to see the http redirect history even if the last redirect is unreachable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, redirect, python-requests

With python requests if I do a HEAD request for an URL that redirects to another URL like this:

```
import requests
url = 'some-url-that-redirects'
r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
```

then `r.history` will show me all the redirects that have occurred.
I have prepared an URL https://bit[.]ly/3waBQaq (wont let me post without [ ] feel free not to use my example URL) that redirects to an unreachable URL https://thisdoesnotexistatleastihopeasdffoo.com/

When I run

```
 import requests
 url = 'https://bit[.]ly/3waBQaq'
 r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
```

this fails with the error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='thisdoesnotexistatleastihopeasdffoo.com',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x7efc84068190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name
> or service not known'))

The error message contains the URL that the bit.ly link redirected to. Is there a way for me to access the information that would be stored in r.history in the case of an unreachable URL?
In the szenario that URL1 redirects to URL2 which redirects to URL3 which is unreachable I need my code to tell me this redirect history instead of an error.